# How do I stream to Chromecast using VLC?

Tags: vlc, chromecast

I just downloaded VLC 3.0 Beta (using ubuntu ppa) and I wanted to know how to set it up to stream to chromecast. It's in the repo's [NEWS](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/dc1384bb63e6b9779817648a485ae02f5dd0ca65/NEWS) that the feature has been added. [Numerous news outlets](http://gizmodo.com/vlc-is-getting-chromecast-support-1686311413) are covering it. But, there is no example of how to actually use it yet.

I know it's not in the GUI (having searched the source code). And, I have no idea how to use the code from the command line.

Here is the [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily) that I used to install it. However, it shouldn't matter. Nor, should the OS or system matter. It's just software. You can build it yourself or [download a binary ("nightly") here](http://nightlies.videolan.org/).

Comment: I would recommend [mkchromecast](http://mkchromecast.com/) Worked like a charm with me from Ubuntu. VLC didn't work for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Building VLC

If you have to build vlc yourself, make sure you have

- `--enable-sout`
- `--enable-chromecast`

## Using VLC

Thus far this feature is not available under the GUI, however you can stream to Chromecast like this,

```
$ vlc --sout="#chromecast{ip=ip_address}" ./video.mp4
```

You can watch the video at the same time with

```
$ vlc --sout="#duplicate{dst=display,#chromecast{ip=ip_address}}" ./video.mp4
```

To make matters even better, you can actually add a delay on the video so it better syncs with the audio (sets the delay to 3100ms).

```
$ vlc --sout="#duplicate{dst=display{delay=3100},#chromecast{ip=ip_address}}" ./video.mp4
```

You can find the list of [options support to chromecast here](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/b42ce7336f90c61aa071f820453ef8885e50b8cb/modules/stream_out/chromecast/cast.cpp#L94), they currently include

- ip
- port
- http-port
- mux
- mime
- video

Comment: That's great. It works for me perfectly (Chromecast 2)! (first command). Installed nightly VLC 3.0 (the Renderer couldn't detect the device but command line version is working like a charm)

Comment: I have a stream open, and I am trying to restream it through chromecast.  However, I am getting the error: error: Failed to start player: "/usr/bin/vlc --sout='#chromecast{ip=192.168.1.80}' ./video.mp4" ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Comment: Almost worked but VLC progress bar goes through the 1h30m of video in a few seconds and then stops streaming

Answer (score 9):

I was unhappy w/ VLC's casting support, so I wrote a dedicated linux GUI for casting a video file.  Might be of use to you, assuming your underlying goal is casting a file, not specifically with VLC.

https://github.com/keredson/gnomecast

[image]

Comment: ^^^ Wonderful app ^^^ No need to futz about with VLC building from source. ^^^ does require Python 3 run-time to be installed -- Runs great on Mint 18.2

Answer (score 4):

There's a post on how to use it via GUI now: http://www.howtogeek.com/269272/how-to-stream-from-vlc-to-your-chromecast/

Basically:

```
Video > Renderer > Scan
Video > Renderer > "Chromecast"
Play media with VLC!
```

Comment: This currently only works for Windows

Comment: @kurdtpage just tested, works on KDE Linux VLC 3.0.8

Comment: Also works here on VLC 3.0.10, but in Playback > Renderer > [my TV name]

Comment: It sometimes does not work on Windows either. When your Win desktop has more than network interface, VLC can not find chromecast using mDNS

Answer (score 2):

This now seems to be available via the GUI using VLC v3 on linux:

> 1. Play video
> 2. Playback > Renderer > your_chromecast_device_name

That's working for me with a .mkv video.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Chrome/ium, you can cast any window to Chromecast. This is how you do it:

1. From any page on your browser (i.e., its startpage), right click an choose "Cast"
2. From the pop-up window, choose to cast your desktop (instead of just one tab)
3. On the next screen, choose to cast from a particular window (instead of the whole desktop)
4. Then, choose VLC or whatever else you'd like to cast

*P.S.: Audio won't be cast using this method*.
P.P.S.: Chromium may have trouble finding your Chromecast; to solve it, you must enable its `chrome://flags/#load-media-router-component-extension` flag.

Sources:

- https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?hl=en
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220893

Answer (score 1):

If VLC doesn`t stream to your chromecast device is because the firewall blocks the ports. Turn the firewall off and enjoy!

Comment: Why would someone who's gone to the effort of setting up a firewall want to turn it off? Surely it would be better to relax one or more of the restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but a solution I found could be helpful.

I encountered an issue where streaming through chromecast was resulting in the demux locally running faster than on the cast, this was fixed by adding `--demux-filter=demux_chromecast` to the command:

```bsh
cvlc --sout="#chromecast{ip=<ip_address>}" --demux-filter=demux_chromecast <source>
```